# How to use jquery dialog in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

So here I'm using jquery dialog to display the page of my page, here's the aspx div code:

```
<div class="BodyDiv" id="DivProjectCode">
    <asp:Label ID="LblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="#ff6c34" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table width="980px">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="120px" height="25px">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Project Code"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" width="5px" class="style1">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text=":"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" width="200px">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TbSearchProjectCode" runat="server" Width="194px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" width="25px">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Support/Image/MagnifierGlass.png"
                            Width="75%" Height="75%" OnClientClick="BtnSearch_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="645px">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div class="BodyDiv" style="overflow: auto; height: 200px">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table width="1024px">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <table width="980px">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="PanelDGV" runat="server" ScrollBars="None" Height="250" Width="515">
                                            <asp:GridView ID="DGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
                                                AllowPaging="true" PageSize="8" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectCode" HeaderText="Project Code" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Project Name" />
                                                    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="../Support/Image/Edit.png" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                                        CommandName="CmdSearch" HeaderText="Edit">
                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                                    </asp:ButtonField>
                                                </Columns>
                                                <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
                                                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $("#DivProjectCode").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            open: function(type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }
        });
        $("#Button1").click(function() {
            $("#DivProjectCode").dialog("open");
        });
                });
</script>
```

the problem is, the whole screen is dimmed including the dialog which isn't supposed to be, when I try to fix it by changing the 'form' to 'form1', the modal works, but the function on the page is not working, do I miss something in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Architecture of updatepanel and jquery Ajax client libraries is different. If we mix them, sometimes it generates JavaScript conflict.

so to avoid read these articles

[UpdatePanel Asynchronous and jquery](http://imak47.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/jquery-effects-not-working-after-updatepanel-asynchronous-request-is-over/)

and

[using jQuery with ASP.NET AJAX](http://encosia.com/2008/06/05/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/)

Comment: correction, sorry for the trouble, but it seems I can use the UpdatePanel without trouble, the problem is in the modal I think, when I set it to 'true' the whole screen including the dialog is dimmed which is troubling me, any suggestion?